# Check if a phone number is valid and active in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, telephony

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a phone number is a real number and active, not a fake number or disconnected number. I would like to import only working numbers into our crm and block phone numbers that look real but do not have a dial tone.

something like ping for phone number with asterisk where I would in a way call the phone without making it ring so I can verify the phone is not disco or bad phone. Is this possible?

Comment: If this were possible, don't you think robo-callers would be using it instead of just sequentially dialing numbers?

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** possible.  Even the phone companies cannot do it to numbers that are not theirs, so customers certainly can't.

Comment: Correct. The phone number standards do not even presume that number resolution is stable, and with callcenters it typically isn't. Calling the same number twice can get you connected to a different line/agent. Such systems may just switch off outside hours, so "disconnected" too is a rather ephemeral state.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can create a application which will pick/select the number and dial via AMI originate command. You have to capture AMI events and wait for originate command success response, after that status = Ringing. Once it ring send the hangup command on the channel via AMI. Now this number is valid and correct. This would be 85-95% accuracy. Hope you got some idea!! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Within North America you need to do LNP / LRN query to check if the phone exists or not and also get the termination/outbound costs. Sometimes it's useful if you want to know from which state this number had been generated(even though it's not accurate due to numbers portability )

Here is one of the service provider
https://www.alcazarnetworks.com/data_services_lnp_lrn.php

FYI: I'm nor working for this company neither sponsoring them or recommending them. I just used them in the past.